# DB2 insert if not present and select

Tags: sql, select, insert, db2

I have a DB2 database table

```
Users
------
userId: BIGINT
```

I need to return a row from the table for a user. If the row is not present it should be inserted and returned. 
Is there a single statement that can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`MERGE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) to insert when the ID does not already exist in the table like so:

```
MERGE INTO Users u (userId) 
USING (VALUES (123)) AS m (userId)
ON u.userId = m.userId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (userID)
        VALUES (m.userId)
ELSE IGNORE
```

There's also a statement that allows you to get what was inserted to the table (search for `data-change-table-reference` on the [`INSERT`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000970.html) page):

```
SELECT *
FROM NEW TABLE (
    INSERT INTO Users(userId)
    VALUES (123), (234)
)
```

Unfortunately, you can't combined these two statements to do it all in one statement.  I think the best you can do if you need unique values is to perhaps do the `INSERT` method along with [compound SQL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html) and handle a [`-803` SQLCODE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00803n.html).

Comment: It's possible to write `INSERT`s that only add a row if a 'duplicate' would exist, meaning you only have to watch for SQLCODE 100 (no rows found).  But yeah, I haven't found a way around this problem either.

Comment: @X-Zero: it would seem logical to me that anything you could do with a normal `INSERT` could be applied to a `MERGE`, but alas, it is not so.  :(

Comment: #headdesk# - sorry, I meant it was possible to write `INSERT`s that only add rows if a duplicate would **not** exist (although, technically, what I said originally is correct too...)

Comment: @X-Zero: I think I got your gist, I was just making a comment that I thought `MERGE` should do the same things as `INSERT` (when you're doing an insert in a merge, obviously :P)